# VIM: omnicomplete, autoselect first item in dropdown-box

Tags: vim

standard for VIM complete is to select the first item in the dropdown-box (and select the desired entry with up and down).
i rather type on till the correct entry is the only one available.

this is done by:

```
set completeopt=longest,menuone
```

problem: now i have to manually press  to select the entry.

there is a mapping which simulates  when the menu is open:

```
inoremap   pumvisible() ? '' : 
  \ '=pumvisible() ? "\Down>" : ""' 

inoremap   pumvisible() ? '' : 
  \ '=pumvisible() ? "\Down>" : ""'
```

vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip1386

but it doesnt work for me. just does nothing.
any idea?

(vim 7.2, win xp)

Answer (score 1):

[Autocomplpop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) plugin: the completion menu is always visible with the first element highlighted.

It's not exactly what you want, but you can type until only one item is visible in the list then simply press enter to insert it.